# FFMPEG support for HLS v4 and v5

Tags: ffmpeg, http-live-streaming

As I understand latest FFMPEG version 2.0.1 supports till HLS version 3.

After going through draft specifications for HLS:

New features introduced in HLS V4 are:

- Segments with bit range support with tag EXT-X-BYTERANGE
- Support for fast forward and fast rewind with tags EXT-X-I-FRAMES-ONLY and EXT-X-I-FRAME-STREAM-INF
- Alternate media option with tag EXT-X-MEDIA

New features introduced in HLS V5 are:

- Introduction of new attributes KEYFORMAT and KEYFORMATVERSIONS for tag EXT-X-KEY
- Introduction of tag EXT-X-MAP
- Support for subtitles by introduction of SUBTITLES value for attribute TYPE of tag EXT-X-MEDIA.

Wanted to know which of the above features are planned to be implemented in FFMPEG library in near future? It will be great if you share the expected delivery dates or versions for these features.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: ffmpeg hls has many bug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of April, 2014, libavformat supports the EXT-X-BYTERANGE and EXT-X-MEDIA features of v4 and the SUBTITLES feature of v5:

http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=history;f=libavformat/hls.c

This work first appeared in the 2.3 release of FFmpeg.

Comment: Do you you have any guides or code that makes use of any of these new features that you could link to?